# Vanilla Uno Platform Solution

Tags: uno

Visual Studio 2017   15.9.16

Start a new Uno App solution.  Updated all the packages.  Build gives couple errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had to downversion the solution's nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console to 1.1.1